When did `apt` output change to include "Done" after "Building dependency tree"?
Recently, I noticed that there was something different about the output from apt update and apt upgrade. After looking at earlier output, the difference seems to be the addition of ... Done after Building dependency tree.
Earlier...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Now...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Does anyone know when this change happened?

If you run apt changelog apt you will see the change in there.  Looks like it was added in apt version 2.1.19 that was released Tue, 09 Feb 2021 10:41:53 +0100
apt (2.1.19) unstable; urgency=medium

  [ Helge Kreutzmann ]
  * German program translation update (Closes: #979848)

  [ Youfu Zhang ]
  * dpkg: fix passing readonly /dev/null fd as stdout/stderr

  [ Diederik de Haas ]
  * Fix apt-acquire-additional-files entity's location.

  [ Wolfgang Schweer ]
  * vendor: Adjust Debian -security codename

  [ Julian Andres Klode ]
  * Include all translations when building the cache (LP: #1907850)

  [ David Kalnischkies ]
  * Various patches uplifted from unfinished fuzzer branches
    - Use 500 MB memory limit for xz/lzma decoding
    - Guess compressor only if no AR nember with exact name exists
    - Free XXH3 state to avoid leak in cache hashing
    - Fail ConfigDir reading if directory listing failed
    - Retire and deprecate _strtabexpand
    - Fix incorrect base64 encoding due to int promotion
    - Don't parse \x and \0 past the end in DeEscapeString
    - Remove Word size limit from ParseQuote and CWord
    - Forbid negative values in unsigned StrToNum explicitly
    - Avoid overstepping bounds in config file parsing
    - Show 'Done' always for 'Building dependency tree'  <---Here it is!
    - Avoid undefined pointer arithmetic while growing mmap
    - Use error reporting instead of assert in rred patching
    - Replace PrintStatus with SendMessage usage
    - Ensure HTTP status code text has sensible content
    - Limit on first patch size only for server-merged patches
    - Use size of the old cache as APT::Cache-Start default
    - Remove spurious periods on progress strings in po/de.po

  [ Frans Spiesschaert ]
  * Dutch program translation update (Closes: #981885)
  * Dutch manpages translation update (Closes: #981883)

 -- Julian Andres Klode <jak@debian.org>  Tue, 09 Feb 2021 10:41:53 +0100


Changelogs for any command can also be viewed at: https://packages.ubuntu.com/
In your case, can be found at: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/apt Then click on Ubuntu Changelog Here is a snip of that page (I put the version, note and release date in Bold):
   apt (2.1.19) unstable; urgency=medium 
  [ Helge Kreutzmann ]
  * German program translation update (Closes: #979848)

  [ Youfu Zhang ]
  * dpkg: fix passing readonly /dev/null fd as stdout/stderr

  [ Diederik de Haas ]
  * Fix apt-acquire-additional-files entity's location.

  [ Wolfgang Schweer ]
  * vendor: Adjust Debian -security codename

  [ Julian Andres Klode ]
  * Include all translations when building the cache (LP: #1907850)

  [ David Kalnischkies ]
  * Various patches uplifted from unfinished fuzzer branches
    - Use 500 MB memory limit for xz/lzma decoding
    - Guess compressor only if no AR nember with exact name exists
    - Free XXH3 state to avoid leak in cache hashing
    - Fail ConfigDir reading if directory listing failed
    - Retire and deprecate _strtabexpand
    - Fix incorrect base64 encoding due to int promotion
    - Don't parse \x and \0 past the end in DeEscapeString
    - Remove Word size limit from ParseQuote and CWord
    - Forbid negative values in unsigned StrToNum explicitly
    - Avoid overstepping bounds in config file parsing

    - Show 'Done' always for 'Building dependency tree'
    - Avoid undefined pointer arithmetic while growing mmap
    - Use error reporting instead of assert in rred patching
    - Replace PrintStatus with SendMessage usage
    - Ensure HTTP status code text has sensible content
    - Limit on first patch size only for server-merged patches
    - Use size of the old cache as APT::Cache-Start default
    - Remove spurious periods on progress strings in po/de.po

  [ Frans Spiesschaert ]
  * Dutch program translation update (Closes: #981885)
  * Dutch manpages translation update (Closes: #981883)

 -- Julian Andres Klode   Tue, 09 Feb 2021 10:41:53 +0100 
